# Will it ever be possible to construct a neural network that could have the features of human brain?

Tags: neural-networks, human-like, human-inspired

I have a question. Will we be able to build a neural network that thinks abstractly, has the creativity, feels and is conscious?

Comment: So basically an AGI (Artificial General Intelligence)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in the distant future they could build a computer powerful enough to simulate the individual neurons of an entire human brain. Then they could carefully copy/paste the connectivity of a sample brain into the computer simulation.

Given that this extreme seems physically possible, it stands to reason that much simpler/smaller alternatives could be engineered in the future assuming continuous advancements in technology.